# Setting up automatic renewals with Stripe API in Java

Tags: java, maven, stripe-payments

I am trying to set up `Automatic Renewal` feature for my `Java Spring MVC` web application, using `Stripe API`. I have added the following `Maven` dependency in my `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.stripe</groupId>
  <artifactId>stripe-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am trying to follow the instructions from https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quickstart#define-plan.

When I try to create a plan as specified in the link using the exact same code, the code shows only errors. I use `eclipse` and there is nothing shown to be imported. Looks like something is missing, but could not find anything from the stripe documentation.

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_...";

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("name", "Basic Plan");
params.put("id", "basic-monthly");
params.put("interval", "month");
params.put("currency", "usd");
params.put("amount", 0);

Plan plan = Plan.create(params);
```

Is there any examples of setting up automatic renewals with Stripe API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. According to what you said, it sounds like the issue you're having is with importing Stripe's Java library into your project, not actually using the library.

Did you add the following at the beginning of your code?

```
import com.stripe.Stripe;
import com.stripe.model.Plan;
```

Comment: how do I process the Stripe webhook events, can you check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131842/using-stripe-webhook-to-send-get-customer-details-for-recurring-payments-using-s