# Using Stripe Webhook to send get customer details for recurring payments using Stripe

Tags: java, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have configured `Stripe` payments in my `Java Spring MVC Web Application`. I am able to add a `Customer`, create a `Plan` and also set up `Subscriptions` for the customer. Since I have recurring payments, I would like to send an email notification to Customers once an invoice is generated and also once the payment is made. From the Stripe documentations, the event types I require are `invoice.upcoming.`, `invoice.payment_succeeded` and `customer.subscription.trial_will_end` since I have trial period for few plans.

I have added a webhook endpoint in my application as follows:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(consumes="application/json", produces="application/json", method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/webhook-endpoint")
    public Response  stripeWebhookEndpoint(@RequestBody String stripeJsonEvent)
    {
        Event event = Event.GSON.fromJson(stripeJsonEvent, Event.class);
        String type = event.getType();
        StripeObject stripeObject = event.getData().getObject();
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    }
```

I am trying to get the `event type` and also the `customer Id` so that I will be able to get the customer from my database and send the email notification based on the event. Since I have my webhook url in my `localhost`, I am unable to trigger actual data from Stripe. Also I was unable to find sample data from the Stripe Documents: https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoice_object. I have also tried [Retrive stripe data from stripe webhook event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342251/retrive-stripe-data-from-stripe-webhook-event), but unable to test it without some sample data.

Is there a way I can get the details required from the event and also test this on my localhost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the development of your web application, in order to check webhooks sent to your localhost, you could use a solution like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Once ngrok is setup and running, configure Stripe to send webhooks to the unique URL provided by ngrok, such as `http://my-super-application.ngrok.io` for example.

ngrok will "forward" the http requests it gets from Stripe to your local machine, exactly as if Stripe would have sent data directly to your local application.

Instead of ngrok, you can also check other solutions, search for "local tunnels" keywords.

To check data sent by Stripe webhooks from the Stripe dashboard, go to the "API" menu, then "Webhooks" tab, click on "TEST" button related to the end point you want to test.

If you click on "Send test webhook" button, Stripe will show you data sent by the webhook under "Request".
(And you can check the request even if the webhook fails to get an answer from your end-point)

For example, for the `invoice.upcoming` event, you will get something like this:

```
{
    "created": 1326853478,
    "livemode": false,
    "id": "evt_00000000000000",
    "type": "invoice.upcoming",
    "object": "event",
    "request": null,
    "pending_webhooks": 1,
    "api_version": "2017-06-05",
    "data": {
      "object": {
        "id": null,
        "object": "invoice",
        "amount_due": 0,
        "application_fee": null,
        "attempt_count": 0,
        "attempted": true,
        "charge": null,
        "closed": true,
        "currency": "jpy",
        "customer": "cus_00000000000000",
        "date": 1503541536,
        "description": null,
        "discount": null,
        "ending_balance": 0,
        "forgiven": false,
        "lines": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": "sub_BN5yNiTkAlQOye",
              "object": "line_item",
              "amount": 500,
              "currency": "jpy",
              "description": null,
              "discountable": true,
              "livemode": true,
              "metadata": {
              },
              "period": {
                "start": 1507604796,
                "end": 1510283196
              },
              "plan": {
                "id": "bplan",
                "object": "plan",
                "amount": 500,
                "created": 1504352393,
                "currency": "jpy",
                "interval": "month",
                "interval_count": 1,
                "livemode": false,
                "metadata": {
                },
                "name": "B plan",
                "statement_descriptor": null,
                "trial_period_days": null
              },
              "proration": false,
              "quantity": 1,
              "subscription": null,
              "subscription_item": "si_1B0LmKE9P3qCpf5erqbpMxkI",
              "type": "subscription"
            }
          ],
          "total_count": 1,
          "object": "list",
          "url": "/v1/invoices/in_1AuB2KE9P3qCpf5ekFh7qpAi/lines"
        },
        "livemode": false,
        "metadata": {
        },
        "next_payment_attempt": null,
        "paid": true,
        "period_end": 1503541536,
        "period_start": 1503541536,
        "receipt_number": null,
        "starting_balance": 0,
        "statement_descriptor": null,
        "subscription": "sub_00000000000000",
        "subtotal": 0,
        "tax": null,
        "tax_percent": null,
        "total": 0,
        "webhooks_delivered_at": 1503541537
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but still how can I get the customer Id from the Event object. When I try event.getUserId(), it shows The method getUserId() from the type Event is deprecated. All I need for now is the event type and the customer Id so that I can send an email to that customer

Comment: According to the previous JSON sample from my answer, if the event type is `invoice.upcoming`, you can parse the JSON data you get from the webhook and read `data.object.customer` property to get the Customer ID. Would it work for your use case?

Comment: StripeObject stripeObject = event.getData().getObject(); will give the object. I still dont see a method to get customer from this object

Comment: The `stripeObject` you get should be cast as an `Invoice` if the webhook type was `invoice.upcoming`. According to the doc https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stripe/model/Invoice.java the Invoice object should have a `getCustomer()` method. But it does not work for you?

Comment: @ Michael Rambeau, It worked, thanks, do you know how we can increase the timeout for the webhook so that I can process the data within the timeout.

Comment: I don't think there is any setting to increase the timeout. What you should do is sending a http response code `200` as soon as you the webhook hits your server, before any processing, no matter what you do next, to ensure that your webhook handler responds on time. FYI it's considered as a "best practice", as mentioned here: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#best-practices.

Answer (score 1):

**The `data` object contain the `customer` ID as `string`**

For `invoice.upcoming` and `invoice.payment_succeeded` the customer ID received as `string` in `data` object.

Following JSON contain the event `data` object for `invoice.upcoming`

```
{
  "object": {
    "object": "invoice",
    "amount_due": 30000,
    "application_fee": null,
    "attempt_count": 0,
    "attempted": false,
    "charge": null,
    "closed": false,
    "currency": "gbp",
    "customer": "cus_ATtwlQqRx75cxxx",
    "date": 1505559958,
    "description": null,
    "discount": null,
    "ending_balance": null,
    "forgiven": false,
    "lines": {
      "object": "list",
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "sub_AU9VONtkvz9xxx",
          "object": "line_item",
          "amount": 30000,
          "currency": "gbp",
          "description": null,
          "discountable": true,
          "livemode": false,
          "metadata": {
          },
          "period": {
            "start": 1505559958,
            "end": 1508151958
          },
          "plan": {
            "id": "package_1",
            "object": "plan",
            "amount": 30000,
            "created": 1492282426,
            "currency": "gbp",
            "interval": "month",
            "interval_count": 1,
            "livemode": false,
            "metadata": {
            },
            "name": "Package 1",
            "statement_descriptor": null,
            "trial_period_days": null
          },
          "proration": false,
          "quantity": 1,
          "subscription": null,
          "subscription_item": "si_1A9BCcJ7IsZfBU9bw4Cxxx",
          "type": "subscription"
        }
      ],
      "has_more": false,
      "total_count": 1,
      "url": "/v1/invoices/in_xxxxxnV9RmPcl/lines"
    },
    "livemode": false,
    "metadata": {
    },
    "next_payment_attempt": 1505563558,
    "paid": false,
    "period_end": 1505559958,
    "period_start": 1502881558,
    "receipt_number": null,
    "starting_balance": 0,
    "statement_descriptor": null,
    "subscription": "sub_AU9VONtkvz9xxx",
    "subtotal": 30000,
    "tax": null,
    "tax_percent": null,
    "total": 30000,
    "webhooks_delivered_at": null
  },
  "previous_attributes": null
}
```